# How can I have only certain users that can decrypt with only one particular key?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

It is straightforward how to create/reuse a role that can decrypt using any key and assign it to a user or group from the IAM console. But what if I want a user of groups to have the role for one of the keys?

Answer (score 2):

The UI is a bit difficult to find and use, but this functionality is hiding in the INFO PANEL section of KMS, just select the key you want first. See the attached screenshot:

[image]